# Nuget "Manage Packages" dialog. Project names are mixed up

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I've got a Visual Studio 2017 solution with several C# class library projects.  On disk they take this structure:

```
MyProduct
    MyCompany
        MyCompany.ModuleA
        MyCompany.ModuleB
        MyCompany.ModuleC
```

But when I look at them in the "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution, the checkboxes show up in the dialog inconsistently.  ModuleC appears strangely.  Like this:

```
MyCompany.ModuleA
MyCompany.ModuleB
MyProduct\MyCompany\MyCompany.ModuleC
```

Also, whenever I build Module C, it keeps creating the following 3 files in its output /obj folder

```
 - MyCompany.ModuleC.csproj.nuget.g.props
 - MyCompany.ModuleC.csproj.nuget.g.targets 
 - project.assets.json
```

Neither of the other two modules does this.

I'm trying to understand the reason for the inconsistency and to fix it if I can.  I have tried combing through the text of the .csproj files for these various projects but I can't spot any differences that might make this happen.  And the raw text of the .SLN file project entry all look consistent for each of the 3 modules.

1. How does NuGet decide what name to put in the Manage Packages for Solution dialog?
2. Why is NuGet creating those temporary files in the output folder for Module C but not Module's A or B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does NuGet decide what name to put in the Manage Packages for Solution dialog?

It is depends on the NuGet manager type, `packages.config` or `PackageReference`.

If the project use `packages.config`, project name will be put in the Manage Packages for Solution dialog. If the project use `PackageReference`, project file name and relative path will be put in it. That because NuGet will update the project file `.csproj` when we install the nuget package with `PackageReference`. So, in the the Manage Packages for Solution dialog, it shows the relative path+project file name, like `ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj`.

> Why is NuGet creating those temporary files in the output folder for
>   Module C but not Module's A or B?

That because NuGet with `PackageReference` controls the msbuild items that are generated for these files into the `obj\projectname.csproj.nuget.g.props`, `obj\projectname.csproj.nuget.g.targets` and `project.assets.json` file.

You can unload your project, check if the project file `MyCompany.ModuleC`use the `PackageReference`, like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>11.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

For some more details, please check this official blog: [NuGet is now fully integrated into MSBuild](https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html).

Comment: Thanks, sounds like PackageReference is the way of the future.   Am I correct in assuming that -- in the PackageReference approach -- the 3 files that it creates (the .props and .json files) should NOT be checked into source control?

Comment: @Joe, Yes, you are right, those files should not check into the source control. When you build your project, those files would be generated.